# Jquery show after hide and vice versa using Tailwind?

Tags: jquery, tailwind-css

**I have searched all answers here:**

I am trying to use `hide()` after `show()` and vice versa, If div hides it does not show again, and vice versa. even tested `toggle` the same ?

I also tested it with pure **Js**, the same issue?

I am using **tailwind**, Is there any issues between Tailwind and Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for me is to remove and add the class `hidden`

```
$('#default_control').removeClass('hidden');

$('#default_control').addClass('hidden');
```

Or toggle the class which is implemented by default in TailWind.